# 2.8: Is it possible to Scale up the Grease Pencil object symbol?

Tags: grease-pencil

I was wondering if it was possible to scale up (or down) the Grease Pencil object symbol? I mean just scale its appearance without scaling the drawing inside, like for example it is possible to scale up the apparent size of an Empty in the Properties panel > Data > Size without changing its real size.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your Grease Pencil object selected, you should find in the "*Data*" panel of the *Properties* window a section called "*Viewport Display*" with an option to control the size of the marker

[image]